# d3.js data not updating when updating circle attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am using d3 force layout. I have to show nodes and links between nodes based on the data I have. I am setting the attributes cx and cy of the circle using the data. circles are show at correct coordinates but d.x and d.y in nodes data not being updated. In tick function source and targets have same coordinates. So, I am not able to draw a line between two nodes.

```
var nodes = [{ id: 1, type: 'startNode', shape: 'circle', fixed: true},{ id: 2, type: 'endNode', shape: 'circle', fixed: true}],
links = [{ source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1]}];

 //force layout init
var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(nodes)
            .links(links)
            .size([width, height])
            .linkDistance(150)
            .charge(-500)
            .on('tick', tick)

var pathElements = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path')
nodeElements = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');

function restart(){

    pathElements = pathElements.data(links);
    pathElements.enter().append('svg:path')
        .attr('class', 'link')
    nodeElements = nodeElements.data(nodes, function(d){
        return d.id;
    });

    var g = nodeElements.enter().append("svg:g")
    g.append("svg:circle")
    .attr('r','40')
    .attr('class','node')
    .attr('cx',function(d){
    console.log(d.id)
        return 100 * d.id;
    })
    .attr('cy',function(d){
        return 100 * d.id;
    })
    force.start();
}

function tick() {
    pathElements.attr('d', function(d) {
        return 'M' + (d.source.x )+ ',' + (d.source.y) + 'L' + (d.target.x) + ',' + (d.target.y);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a constructive criticism: can you please rephrase *all*  your question? I (kind of) understand your problem because I'm a D3 coder, but for anybody it's better having a clear notion of the problem before proposing any answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado added extra info. any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's better now. However, it seems to me that you don't want a force directed chart.